# Detail to detail drillthrough in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

I have a Master page in a Power BI report with a list of IDs. For each ID's there are multiple detail pages set up as drillthrough pages - e.g. Overview Detail and Usage Detail. Each detail page takes in an ID and you can drillthrough from the master page to get to either.

What I would like to do is link the detail pages to each other. So I have filtered in ID 1 and looking at the Overview Detail and I want to have a menu or link to "See Usage Details" which would drillthrough with the same ID to the Usage Detail page (and vica versa). I could then break my detail pages up into a whole set of pages and almost have a tab menu on each to explore a particular ID.

I tried tables with hyperlinks (and querystrings) but it was getting really messy. The button links and bookmarks cannot take in a dynamic drillthrough filter.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that with bookmarks.

First thing would be to create a bookmark, which takes a user to the desired page (from drilled page A to drilled page B). Bookmarks can be found here:

[image: bookmarks]

You need to turn Data and Display options off. The bookmark should only move a user between pages. Add button to Drillpage A with the bookmark as an action. If you need it both ways, do the same thing with Drillpage B.

After that, add slicer with IDs (column you use to drill) to both Drillpages and mark sync between them to True (option dialog should pop up when copypasting the visual, or turn ON sync pane here:

[image: sync sliders]

Then just hide both slicers so the user is not aware of them (via selection page - turn on just over Sync slicers option). I think the slicer should keep the ID, which was used to drillthrough into the page, thus providing the desired behavior.

Another option that comes into mind, is to make a small drillthrough table, which would contain only ID column, so a user could use it to drill from drillpageA to drillpageP, but I've never found it user-friendly.